# ASP.Net 5 MVC 6, how to use shared Error.cshtml as default error response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

**ASP.Net 5 MVC 6, how to use shared Error.cshtml as default error response**

*when using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics UseExceptionHandler middleware with a razor view*

If you look at the sample code at https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/dev/samples/ExceptionHandlerSample/Startup.cs
explaning how to use Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics ErrorHandler middleware for ASP.Net 5,a comment say:

// Normally you'd use MVC or similar to render a nice page.

Ok, but how to do that ?

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the error handler to show an error page.
        app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
        {
            // Normally you'd use MVC or similar to render a nice page.
            errorApp.Run(async context =>
            {
```

Comment: is it possible to use app.UseExceptionHandler with default error page? I want to capture error details, but keep existing behaviour and pages.

Comment: @SemenShekhovtsov did you read the response : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626442/2940908

Answer (score 36, accepted):

in Startup class:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

in HomeController:

```
public IActionResult Error()
{
    var feature = this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
    return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml", feature?.Error);
}
```

the Error.cshtml view can look like :

```
@model Exception

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Oops!";
}
<h1 class="text-danger">Oops! an error occurs</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
@if (Model != null)
{
    @Html.ValueFor(model => model.Message)
}
```

this code is part of project available on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/aguacongas/chatle)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to actually work - at least not using IIS Express with VS2015. I still get the default error message.

`"HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found 
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."`

Comment: I didn't retest it with beta4

Comment: @Soulhuntre Error handler handles uncactched exception, not 404, you need to create your own middleware or use iss settings to customize 404 page

Comment: I have been trying to find how to reference the error for a while now. Thanks! (this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();)

Answer (score 8):

To Handle 404s and Internal Errors you need to modify the error signature.

I've explicitly commented out the debugging error handlers in my Dev environment in the Startup.cs.  If you don't want to do this use the environment variable in the project.

Add this to the Startup.cs

```
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // Uncomment when done testing error handling
        //app.UseBrowserLink();
        //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        //app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

        // Comment when done testing error handling
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

        //For more details on creating database during deployment see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615859
        try
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                .CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .Database.Migrate();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }


    // Lines Skipped For Brevity ....


    // Add this line above app.Mvc in Startup.cs to Handle 404s etc
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");
```

Add this to the HomeController.cs

```
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features;

    // id = Http Status Error
    public IActionResult Error(String id)
    {
        var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

        var undhandledException = feature?.Error;
        var iisError = id;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Great! `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");` is what I needed

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and MVC 5:

The following is in the Controller class:

```
public ActionResult Save(MyObject obj)
{
    try
    {
         //Write cde here that could break..maybe an update or new object etc
         //...
         ///successful
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(e, "Home", "Error"));
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //redir to list
}
```

This will go to the Error.cshtml in the Views\Shared\ folder.
This works for me.

Comment: The question is about MVC 6 not 5. and your response is per action, not the default behavior