# How can one get the latest error thrown in a dotnet core asp.net application?

Tags: .net-core

I'm liking the dotnet core development, but in managing errors, I'd like to be able to get a handle on the exception that is thrown.  Currently I have an error controller that gets fired like it is configured in the startup.cs (                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");) and a corresponding error view.  But I don't know how to get the exception from the controller so I can process the error message for my users.  In the old asp.net, I could get this information by running a  Server.GetLastError, or by leveraging the OnError event, but these are not available in dotnet core. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe part of this is just getting used to middleware.  I found what I needed here.
[ASP.Net 5 MVC 6, how to use shared Error.cshtml as default error response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626353/asp-net-5-mvc-6-how-to-use-shared-error-cshtml-as-default-error-response)